# how to populate select menu in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I`m trying to add options to my select menu in my custom plugin. I want to get these options from array that I have and with forearch or for to create these options.How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Could you show us your code that generates the select box? If I'm guessing right, you might be able to do something like

```
var things = [];
var your = ["Derpy","Fluttershy","Applejack"];
for(var i = 0; i < your.length; i++) {
    // The two values used to separate actual and display values if needed
    things[i] = [your[i],your[i]];
}

// snip snip
tab.add({
    type: 'select',
    label: 'myAwesomePonySelector',
    id: 'myAwesomePonySelector',
    items : things
    // your other definitions, like onShow and commit
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Glad to help! I recently did something like this as well and didn't find an example